# Atom editor: How to jump back and forward

Tags: atom-editor

I'm used to PHP Storm where you can easily jump back and forwards to where the cursor previously was.
Is there such a feature in the atom editor?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you are looking for the package "last-cursor-position":

https://atom.io/packages/last-cursor-position

If you want to modify the key binding, click on "view code" for the package and edit the file `keymaps\last-cursor-position.cson`

**Edit:** Or better, override keybindings in your `keymap.cson`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in unision with "go-to-line:toggle" which is a pretty core use-case. Eg. Going to line 100, copying something, then going back

Answer (score 5):

An extra step for those who got used to toolbars in IDEs: to add "back" and "forward" actions to toolbar, I've installed these two packages *in addition* to last-cursor-position mentioned above:

- https://atom.io/packages/tool-bar
- https://atom.io/packages/flex-tool-bar

Then edited the tool bar (there is a gear button on default flex toolbar for this) by adding two buttons that refer to last-cursor-position shortcuts:

```
{
  type: "button"
  icon: "arrow-left"
  callback: "last-cursor-position:previous"
  tooltip: "Back"
}
{
  type: "button"
  icon: "arrow-right"
  callback: "last-cursor-position:next"
  tooltip: "Forward"
}
```

Got this [toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAqn7.png)

Comment: Nice solution, combining two packages

Answer (score 1):

1) [cursor-history](https://atom.io/packages/cursor-history) package, will let you jump between your last and current cursor position.

Install package using command `apm install cursor-history` or from atom editor.

2) [python-tools](https://atom.io/packages/python-tools) package, will let you jump to your function/go-to-declaration.

Install package using command `apm install python-tools` or from atom editor.

[Tested on: atom 1.45.0, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, python3]